# How to get the source code of current page as a variable in php

Tags: php, preg-match

for example my page is like below code. I know how to extract "this" from the string by preg_match but how do i get the source code of current page as a variable in php.

```
<body>
<p>I need to find "this" word from "this" string</p>
</body>
```

Comment: It is for the current page so i can't use the file get contents because the page is not loaded. As i know first the php is loaded and then html.

Answer (score 3):

Call `ob_start()` at the beginning of your script, then [`ob_get_clean()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php), at the bottom. It will return the output contents of the script as a String, which can you store in a variable. So, from your example:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<body>
<p>I need to find "this" word from "this" string</p>
</body>
<?php $foo = ob_get_clean(); ?>
```

Comment: hi, by using ob my content got disappeared. I can't see my content anymore.

Comment: Yea. You probably want to echo it out, since you put it into a variable.

Comment: yes i needed that , thanks for the help. Now can it be possible in anyway that i use the $foo in the head of my file. I know its stupid . The thing is i need to check something in the body and then pass the value to javascript which will be used in the body of content.

Comment: Got it. thanks for the help jameson.